# How to split a string to figure float with figure name, label and caption?

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, captions, strings

I am struggling with a shorthand macro that converts a string to a figure. At the end is a working, but unstable version what I am trying to do. The goal is to parse make a command (or macro) like this:

```
\fig{figure_name.png fig:figure_label
This is the figure caption with a reference \ref{fig:another_figure}.  
}
```

that corresponds to traditional version of this:

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphicx[width=\columnwidth]{figure_name.png}
  \caption{This is the figure caption with a reference \ref{fig:another_figure}.}
  \label{fig:figure_label}
\end{figure}
```

Or better yet, the macro format could have key-value pairs in the beginning and caption at the end. This is my final target. Like this:

```
\fig{(figure_name.png, label=fig:figure_label, width=\columnwidth)
    This is the figure caption with a reference \ref{fig:another_figure}.  
 }
```

The problem that I have is that the code below gets stuck in a forever loop when references change or when I compile once with an error. When I add a new label I have to comment all lines containing `\ref{}` and compile the a few times to get references correct. Then uncomment all `\ref`s and compile to get the correct version.

What's wrong or how should do this? I would appreciate a well commented code. I have trouble understanding lines like this: `\tl_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {-}`. A lua solution is also fine.

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\fig{>{\SplitList{ }}m}
{%
  \xdef\captionWords{}
    \ProcessList{#1}{\myitem}%
    \firstitemtrue
    \seconditemfalse
    \caption{\captionWords \label{\thisLabel}}
  \end{figure}

}

\newif\iffirstitem
\firstitemtrue  
\newif\ifseconditem
\seconditemtrue
\newcommand\myitem[1]{%
  \iffirstitem

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{figures/#1}\\
    \firstitemfalse
    \seconditemtrue
  \else  
    \ifseconditem 
      \xdef\thisLabel{#1}
      \seconditemfalse
    \else 
      \xdef\captionWords{\captionWords\  #1}
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

Comment: can't help with most of this, but you *do* need `\protect` before `\ref` when it's in a caption (or other "movable" argument, like a section heading).

Comment: How about something even more verbose: `\fig{filename=.., label=.., width=.., caption=..}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, I'll look into `\protect`

Comment: @Werner Good idea, also it could be something like: first unnamed argument is a shorthand for filename=... if it exists, second unnamed argument is a shorthand for label=... if it exists. and the named arguments override unnamed arguments. Then you could use both verbose and less verbose versions as you see fit. This is a complicated function, but once you get it working...

Comment: @Juha Your proposed input is very error prone. It's much better to have keys explaining what the following input is for.

Comment: Egreg: that is actually Python syntax apart form delimiters and aphostropes. I have this alteady with python preprosessor but I want to do it with native latex (or luatex) for portability. I write a lot of scientific articles and I only need four things: equations, refs, cites and figures. Figure syntax takes too much space on the screen.